# Delete record with jQuery and AJAX Delete not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My problem is that when I press yes on delete confirmation the db record goes away, but if I refresh the page it comes back.

Maybe I have to put the language and the id inside the Ajax URL?

If yes how can I do this?

Please forgive me I am still learning.

This is for java eclipse and SQL database

```
var assetId;
var batchId; 

 function cancelOpname(){
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      url: urlPage + "opname/cancel",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: data,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('.loader').fadeIn();
        },
        complete: function() {
        $('.loader').fadeOut();
        },   
        success: function()  {
            if (data.errorResult == false) {
            console.log("Success: else "); 
               javascript:window.history.back();
            } else {
                $('.loader').fadeOut();
            }
        },
        error : function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        }
    });
  }
```

no error but ajax and jQuery not working

Comment: where's the java?

Comment: Are you checking the DB to see that the record has been deleted?  Or just relying on the UI?   If it's going in the DB, then there's something bring it back - but most likely you're not actually deleting it.

Comment: Please also clarify: is the confirmation not working or the delete not working?  Your question title says the confirmation (which you've not included) but the question says it's not being deleted (regardless of the confirmation) (which you've *also* not included).

Comment: deleted not working. i'm sorry

Comment: You need to determine whether it's the AJAX request that's failing or it's your server side Java. From there you can start to debug. Right now we can't help you given the limited information you've provided.